# How to get opening balance

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2008

I am facing an issue in Crystal Reports. I am not able to get or solve the issue of opening balance which is the closing balance of previous day. Let me show you my ledger structure in MS SQL.

```
[dbo].[ledgerreport](
[ledgerautonumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[serialno] [varchar](50) NULL,
[accountiddr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[accountnamedr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[accountidcr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[accountnamecr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[dateledger] [date] NULL,
[voucherid] [varchar](50) NULL,
[debitamount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[creditamount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[description] [varchar](50) NULL,
[closingbalance] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[unit] [varchar](50) NULL
```

and my code that im using in vb.net

```
 Try
        con = New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
        con.Open()
        Dim cb2 As String = "insert into ledgerreport(serialno,dateledger,voucherid,debitamount,creditamount,description,closingbalance,unit,accountiddr,accountnamedr,accountidcr,accountnamecr) VALUES (@d100,@d101,@d102,@d103,@d104,@d105,@d106,@d107,@d108,@d109,@d110,@d111)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(cb2)
        cmd.Connection = con
        ' Prepare command for repeated execution
        cmd.Prepare()
        ' Data to be inserted
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d100", row.Cells(0).Value) 'serial no
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d101", row.Cells(3).Value) 'dateledger
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d102", row.Cells(2).Value) 'voucher id
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d103", row.Cells(7).Value) 'debit amount
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d104", row.Cells(8).Value) 'credit amount
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d105", row.Cells(6).Value) 'description
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d106", row.Cells(13).Value) 'closing balance
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d107", row.Cells(1).Value) 'unit
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d108", row.Cells(4).Value) 'accountiddr
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d109", row.Cells(5).Value) 'accoutnamedr
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d110", AccountidcrTextEdit.Text) 'accountidcr
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d111", cashaccounttxtedit.Text) ' accountnamecr
  

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            End If
        Next
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & " " & "Error Code : CPV-LG-002", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error Code : CPV-LG-002")
    End Try
```

Now what I am doing here is whenever user do a transaction in cash payment, the ledger code save the details in SQL table. And in report I use fields and parameters to generate report, but I am not able to get the opening balance that is the closing balance of my last day report. Here I am facing issue: how I can get opening balance using my above code?

Comment: 2008? Someone should be concerned about that. All columns in your table are nullable? Big problem. Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). More importantly, no one can help you without knowing your schema. Your code simply inserts rows into your table - so the connection to CR is unclear. What query would you use in SSMS to get the closing balance for any particular date?

Comment: sir this is what im trying to figure out becz i have no idea to do a ledger. if possible can u guide me with your experience by keeping a side my codes .